# Added App Transport Security, Still giving Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking, instagram

I have added App Transport Security in my app's Info.plist file, but when I tried to access this URL http://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=%@"
it gives me an error:

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext
>   HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary
>   exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

Comment: Please add SS where you add Transport Security.

Comment: you have to ON keychain sharing from capabilities.

Comment: Show the ATS settings from your info.plist

Comment: jusgt check your instagran access token key that you pass and your app id is valid or not

Comment: Please try with https:   **https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=%@**

Comment: Yes, that is a good point. Simply use the https URL to access Instagram and you don't need to worry about ATS

Answer (score 1):

You probably have not configured `App Transport Security Settings` the right way.

Please double check you have something similar to the image below.

[image: simple .plist exception]

If that still does not work, you could try adding the domain itself as an exception. You'd use a configuration similar to the image below. (`akamaihd.net`, `facebook.com` and `fbcdn.net` are just an example).

[image: advanced .plist exception]

Answer (score 0):

Please try with HTTPS URL:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=%@

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**you have to ON keychain sharing from capabilities**

```
PROJECT NAME > CAPABILITIES > KEY CHAIN SHARING (ON)
```